# VK API, удаление сообщение бота

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Есть такой кусок кода:

```py
def deleter(peer_id, all, cm):
    vk.method('messages.delete', {'peer_id': peer_id, 'delete_for_all': all, 'cmids': cm, 'group_id': ***})
```

Данная часть удаляет сообщение от человека, приславшего команду. Пытаясь найти способ удалить сообщение бота (который идет ответом на команду), ничего не получилось. `Conversation_message_id` бота не отслеживается кодом. Каким способом можно попробовать удалить сообщение бота (пробовал способ через cmid+1, но это крайне нестабильный метод)?

Comment: Почему "не отслеживается кодом"? Что мешает отслеживать?

Comment: Пробовал через print выводить сообщения, не видит. Есть конечно способ через второй код или поток, но надеюсь на другой вариант)

Comment: Какие сообщения? Что означает «не видит»? Не видит что? О чём речь вообще?

Comment: `сообщение бота (который идет ответом на команду)` значит вы отправляете сообщение через _messages.send_. А что сложного от этого метода получить cmid? Вот [страница](https://dev.vk.com/method/messages.send#%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82) документации.